# Code::Blocks 13.12 error - CC1.exe has stopped working

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks 13.12 for programming in C. After building and running my simple HelloWorld.c program, it gives an error.

Error: An alert box pop up saying -"cc1.exe has stopped working.A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

I tried using Notepad++ , the same pop up appears saying a.exe has stopped working.

I am a naive,so have no idea on how to deal with this.
My queries:

1) Am I using an outdated version? If not, how can I get rid of this problem?

2) Which is the most efficient IDE available for C/C++ if Code::Blocks is not that efficient? 
My requirement"
-I had been using Turbo C and it doesn't give errors like segmentation fault and other memory    related errors that we get in online Compilers or compilers of competitive programming.So, I need an efficient compiler which behaves same as online compilers, so I don't get stuck while solving problems during competitive programming.

This is the simple code giving error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("Hello world!");
    //return 0;
}
```

Edit:

Even after changing the code to return int, it's giving an error.I tried editing the code as below, but the same window is being popped up again.

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try googling something like "cc1 has stopped working"

Comment: Neither of the supplied code has the main() correct. It should be: 'int main()'

Comment: I have to guess a bit here, as you have not included the script that your using to do the compile/link/execute sequence.  However, from my experience, I think the problem is with the driving script, not with the program.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with your code, though indeed, as pointed out in the comments, neither `void main()` nor `int main(void)` is considered correct, but that's not what's causing the problem. cc1.exe is a MinGW-related file (MinGW is the GCC port for Windows that Code::Blocks uses by default for compilation); if it's crashing, it's possible the installation is corrupt.

I suggest you try reinstalling MinGW - remove Code::Blocks, install the standalone MinGW version, then download Code::Blocks without the compiler suite, install it and configure to use your version of MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to choose,

> Select target -> Release

from the `Build` menu. It took lots of time for me to find this!